# How to configure Privoxy HTTPS inspection?

Tags: ssl, https, privoxy

After following through the docs at [www.privoxy.org](http://www.privoxy.org), I have created a cert and key with openssl, placed them into the CA directory at /usr/local/etc/privoxy/CA/, and given permissions to the privoxy (also tried root) user and group. The same certificate has been accepted into my Firefox as a trusted authority.

However, when trying to access any site through Firefox (configured with local proxy port 8118), FF complains about "HTTPS version of example.org is not available"/"This website does not supply ownership information." or "PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR".

The privoxy logs read:

```
Error: A website key already exists but there's no matching certificate. Removing /var/lib/privoxy/certs/<longcode>.pem before creating a new key and certificate.
Error: Loading issuer certificate /usr/local/etc/privoxy/CA/cacert.crt failed: PK - Read/write of file failed
Error: generate_host_certificate failed: -1
Error: Failed to open a secure connection with the client
```

It seems no matter what I do, the cert file cannot be read. Running privoxy as root/privoxy/$USER user, or assigning broad permissions and ownership to the /CA directory have no effect. How is this normally configured?

Comment: "Running privoxy as root/privoxy/$USER user," - I have no idea what you are trying to say here, but the logs indicate a simple permissions issue.